# Importing zone.js does not solve test error

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have tests that fails due to the following:

```
Error: zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
        Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing
```

I have tried different suggestions found online that suggests putting the following at top of test.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/testing';
import 'zone.js';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

and

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import 'zone.js';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

Unfortunately these suggestion makes no difference.
Are there any other ways that could fix my problem?

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
 }

"devDependencies": {
   ...
   "karma": "~6.3.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
   "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
   "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
   "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
}
```